# jQuery indexing Iframe contents

Tags: jquery, iframe, indexing

I have this code which will alert index position of element:

```
var qq = $('li').index('*');
alert(qq);
```

The problem is that the `li` is in Iframe. I suppose I have to do something like:

```
    var qq = $('iframe').contents().find('li').index('*');
    alert(qq);
```

But it doesn't work. Its giving me `-1` as index which is not good.

Comment: Just in case of, be aware of  same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @roasted The content is on my server

Comment: Is the iframe loading a remote url?

Comment: @Skelly Im not sure what you mean by that. The Iframe is my own document

Comment: I was thinking cross-domain problem too, and just making sure the iframe has local content.